# Any element of a field may be expressed as the sum of non-zero two elements of the field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Am I correct in this conclusion?

Any element of a field may be expressed as the sum of some two **non-zero** elements of the field.

I.e. For any $z \in F$ there is $x, y \neq 0 \in F$ such that $z = x + y$

Proof:

$z  + (-y) = x$

Certainly. (Any $z$ added to the additive inverse of some $y$ is certainly equal to some $x$ in $F$)

Hence

$z + (-y) + y = x + y$

$z = x + y$

Comment: Absolutely correct! It hold for any additive group, by the way. Not just fields.

Comment: Sorry, I meant two non-zero elements. Does my conclusion still hold?

Comment: "$z+(-y)=x$" is not a proof, because you don't say what the elements are. And you have no warrant for asserting you have the equality. In short the equality doesn't mean anything until you tell us who $z$, $x$, and $y$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, we may assume without loss of generality that $z\ne 0$, as $0 = 1 + (-1)$ in every field.

The proof fails because you do not know that $y \ne z$, and thus it could be the case that $x = 0$, meaning you have not found your desired pair of nonzero elements. Your proof thus makes the implicit assumption that there are two distinct nonzero elements $y$ and $z$, a statement true in every field except $\mathbb F_2$. And sure enough, the statement is false in $\mathbb F_2$: $1 = 0 + 1$ and $1 = 1+0$ are the only ways to express $1$ as the sum of two elements of that field.

Answer (score 2):

There is but one exception: the field of two elements, $\mathbb{F}_2$. In this field, the element $1$ cannot be expressed as the sum of two nonzero elements, since the only nonzero element is $1$ but $1+1=0$.

If the field has more than two elements, though, then the result holds. In fact, it holds in any group (commutative or not): Let $G$ be a group with at least three elements, let $e$ denote its identity element, and let $z\in G$.

Let $x$ be any element of $G$ that is different from $e$ and from $z$ (possible since $G$ has at least three elements); (if $z=e$, then just pick any $x\neq e$). Let $y=x^{-1}z$. Since $x\neq z$, then $y\neq e$. And we have $xy = xx^{-1}z = z$.

Interpreting this additively in a field, given $z$, pick $x$ to be any element of the field different from $0$ and from $z$, and take $y=z-x$. Since $x\neq z$, then $y\neq 0$, and we have $x+y = x+(z-x) = z$.